# Unregistered user, or user with multiple unregistered accounts

Tags: support, user-accounts

There is a Mike Olds who wrote [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/39016/471) and [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/39014/471), with [this account](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/19137/mike-olds) and [this account](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/19138/mike-olds). Both appear to be the same person, but writing different answers with different unregistered accounts.

It appears that on every new session he uses this site, he may be doing so as a different user.

This appears to be a problem. How can this be prevented or avoided?

And Mike Olds probably needs a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users are allowed to use unregistered accounts.

I brought up this topic with him via comments once and he declined, saying (I forget the exact words he used) that he will no longer register on an internet sites (e.g. this site) -- so that's his choice.

Nevertheless each of his posts is welcome (good answers), and his meta-behaviour as a user is good (answering questions, not criticising other users, not using multiple accounts in order to evade moderation).

I believe he is the author/editor of http://obo.genaud.net/

Comment: "Users are allowed to use unregistered accounts." really, or another "moods rule", personal used to manifest mod opinion?

Comment: @SamanaJohann Yes really -- "Users are allowed to use unregistered accounts" is SE policy -- it is "by design" i.e. if SE didn't want to permit it then their software wouldn't allow it. I think it's because SE want to make it possible for users to participate easily.

Comment: It's sometimes easier for me and other users if any regular/frequent users do have registered accounts (also users aren't allowed to use unregistered or alternate accounts to evade moderation, e.g. to post even while their main account is suspended).

Comment: So what to follow? Moods/opinion/guesses or the ever changing TOS, or simply 5 precepts?